# Reset FlutterFragment content using Flutter Engine while using FlutterFragment

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-engine

I am using a Flutter module inside my Android Application.
I have defined a global Flutter Engine in a pre heated state in my Activity and is attaching it to a FlutterFragment as and when required in a particular Scenario.
Below is pre heated engine called once the onCreate()on Activity is triggered.

```
void setupFlutterEngine(){
        FlutterEngine flutterEngine=new FlutterEngine(getApplicationContext());

//        Start executing Dart code in the FlutterEngine.
        flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().executeDartEntrypoint(
                DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
        );

//      Cache the pre-warmed FlutterEngine to be used later by FlutterFragment.
        FlutterEngineCache
                .getInstance()
                .put(FLUTTER_ENGINE_CACHE_TAG, flutterEngine);

    }
```

Everything is working fine, I am instantiating and adding the cached engine to my FlutterFragment as below :

```
FlutterEngine flutterEngine=FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get(FLUTTER_ENGINE_CACHE_TAG);

flutterMethodChannel = new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), methodChannelTag);

flutterMethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull MethodChannel.Result result) {
                
            }
        });

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine); 

flutterFragment = FlutterFragment
                .withCachedEngine(FLUTTER_ENGINE_CACHE_TAG)
                .renderMode(RenderMode.surface)
                .transparencyMode(TransparencyMode.opaque)
                .shouldAttachEngineToActivity(true)
                .build();
```

I want to finish the current view of flutter module when the fragment is destroyed but do not want to destroy the engine, I would like to reuse the FlutterEngine and want to re-start from the very first screen under main() method in Flutter module when the fragment is again added.

Comment: Hi, any solutions of this? I encountered the same requirement here.

Comment: Hi Nitant, Did you find any solution of this ?